# How to print out a specific column from MySQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to print out all the columns that has the same path as the one that i get from an Image. The main problem is that path='path' is read as a string with the value "path" instead of the value that i have in my path-variable. path = path without the '' is not accepted as a value, and therefore i can't print the columns. if i directly insert path='C:\Users....\' here, it prints out the right columns.

```
public void getImageInfoFromDatabase(Image image) {
    String path = image.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE path='path'"); 

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt(1);
            String title = resultSet.getString(2);
            String path = resultSet.getString(3);
            String tags = resultSet.getString(4);
            String latitude = resultSet.getString(5);
            String longitude = resultSet.getString(6);
            java.util.Date timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(7);
            System.out.println(id + " " + title + " " + path + " " + tags + " " + latitude + " " + longitude + " " + timestamp);
        }

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error. ");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: The question is "how to pass variable to query" and answer is "use prepared statement". You should edit your post with clear explanation of the problem and your answer could be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i had to use the setString method from PreparedStatement to input a value at a specific index. The complete functioning code looks like this:

```
    public boolean getImageInfoFromDatabase(Image image) {
        boolean success = true;
        String string = image.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        string = string.replace("\\", "\\\\");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT  * FROM image_table WHERE path = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, string);
            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt(1);
                String title = resultSet.getString(2);
                String path = resultSet.getString(3);
                String tags = resultSet.getString(4);
                String latitude = resultSet.getString(5);
                String longitude = resultSet.getString(6);
                java.util.Date timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(7);
                System.out.println(id + " " + title + " " + path + " " + tags + " " + latitude + " " + longitude + " " + timestamp);
                success = true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;

        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Variable `string` is a really bad name for path to image.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE path='path'
```

Comment: This is what i've already tried, without success unfortunately. If i put path='path' it will only search for a column that has a path that IS "path", and not the String path that i have created.